# Strugging with spring SimpleJdbcCall to call Oracle function

Tags: java, oracle, procedure

I am struggling with the below code to make it work, searching documentation and forums and stucked. 
Finally I decided to ask you for help.
What I have is package with TYPES, FUNCTION declarations and FUNCTION BODY declaration.
In future I would like to use SYNONYM to MYPACKAGE (This is only mock - I will not have package and types declarations in my database, but use dblink to external database and Java code to run procedures / functions, but now I don't have this dblink accessible) and MYPACKAGE will be something accessible through dblink:

```
create public synonym dblink_MYPACKAGE for SOME_SCHEMA.MYPACKAGE@dblink_externalDB;
```

and I will be using dblink_MYPACKAGE instead of MYPACKAGE in Java Code.
 (but this doesn't matter does it?) The external database is not ours, so we CAN'T change anything there...

```
public class TestClassSpringBased {

private DataSource dataSource;

private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

@Override
public void testMe(Integer id) {

    int iid = 1;
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("IN_1", iid);

    Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);

}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

    this.jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withCatalogName("MYPACKAGE")
            .withProcedureName("MYFUNCTION")
            .withReturnValue()
            .useInParameterNames("IN_1")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlInOutParameter("IN_1", OracleTypes.NUMBER),
                    new SqlInOutParameter("OUT_1", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "MYPACKAGE.CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE",
                            new SqlReturnType() {
                                public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int colIndx, int sqlType,
                                        String typeName) throws SQLException {

                                    return null; //just let it work, the I will think what to write here
                                }
                            }));

}

}





 create or replace 
 PACKAGE         MYPACKAGE IS 


   TYPE CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE_R IS RECORD (
     C1 VARCHAR2(60),   
     C2    VARCHAR2(30)

  );

  TYPE CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE IS TABLE OF CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE_R 
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;



 FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(
   IN_1 IN INTEGER, OUT_1 OUT CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE )
 RETURN VARCHAR2;


   END;



create or replace 
 PACKAGE BODY MYPACKAGE  IS

   FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(
     IN_1 IN INTEGER, OUT_1 OUT CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE )
    RETURN VARCHAR2  IS

  BEGIN

 SELECT *  BULK COLLECT INTO OUT_1
    FROM  SOME_TABLE;
   RETURN 'return param';
 END MYFUNCTION; 

  END MYPACKAGE ;
```

The ERROR is:
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call MYPACKAGE.MYFUNCTION(?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17074]; invalid name pattern: MYPACKAGE.CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: MYPACKAGE.CUSTOMELEMENTSTYPE

The problem is only with OUT parameter, the same code works, when I dont pass OUT parameter and run it against another version of MYFUNCTION, that has not OUT parameter.

I tried also with OracleTypes.ARRAY (invalid name pattern) and OracleTypes.OTHER (Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: wrong column type: 1111)

Comment: do you solve this problem ? i am facing something like this

Comment: As far as I remember, we did it on Oracle. It was a type nod suported by jdbc so we wrote a wrapped function / prodecure on Oracle calling the original function but the new one had correct parameter types. The original one was accessed by dblink as it wasnt our server, we couldn change anything there.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that You use incorrect method call:
 Your code:
    **.withProcedureName("MYFUNCTION")[..]**
should be replaced by 
    **.withFunctionName[...]**

here is some simple examle of whole function call:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(txManager.getDataSource());
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbc)
            .withCatalogName("p_adm_www")
            .withFunctionName("fn_usr_get_login_sequence")
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("RETURN", OracleTypes.NUMBER))
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    jdbcCall.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
    BigDecimal returnId = jdbcCall.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, null);
    return returnId.longValue();
```

Comment: offcourse You can add more IN or INOUT parameters, the same works for me without any problems.