# Datatype mismatch when calling stored function

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

There is an Oracle stored function :

```
create or replace function create_role(p_role varchar2)
return pls_integer
is
    v_role role.role_db%type;
begin
    v_role := regexp_replace(p_role, '[[:space:]]*',''); /* suppression des espaces entre les caractères */
    v_role := lower(v_role);
    execute immediate 'create role ' || v_role ;
    return 1;
exception
    when others then /* role or user of same name already exists */
        return 0;
end;
```

I want to call it from Spring :

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Integer insert(Role role) {

        String roleDb = role.getLib().startsWith("role_sse_") ? StringUtils.stripAccents(role.getLib()).toLowerCase() : StringUtils.stripAccents("role_sse_"+role.getLib()).toLowerCase();

        simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                         .withFunctionName("create_role");

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_role", roleDb);

        Integer ret = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Integer.class, in);

        if (ret == 1) {

            Session sessionDynamic = Utils.createDynamicSession(env);

            role.setDb(roleDb);

            sessionDynamic.persist(role);
            sessionDynamic.flush();
            sessionDynamic.close();

        }

        return ret;

    }
```

At runtime I got error : `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: thank you @Slava for adding the tag Oracle , otherwise Dave CK would not have answered me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think PLS_INTEGER is a standard type.

If you are able to change the function to return a standard NUMBER type that might fix it.

Another option might be to look at...

[Strugging with spring SimpleJdbcCall to call Oracle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506309/strugging-with-spring-simplejdbccall-to-call-oracle-function)

Comment: I already set the return type to NUMBER but I got the BigDecimal exception :) So how to solve the BigDecimal exception ?

Comment: Can you post the modified code and the new exception?

Comment: no need to post the code because the answer in the link you provided gave me the idea to treat the BigDecimal return type. So I restored the stored function return type to be NUMBER.